# what's an easily scalable way to set a cookie on my domain?

Tags: cookies, scalability, session-cookies, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to do some simple cookie tracking and need to find an easily scalable way to set a cookie.  The setup needs only to set a cookie, no server side logic needed, no uniqueness or token required.  Something as simple as "HAS_VISITED=true;" is all I really need.  Is there some cloud service that does this?  I need it to be on my domain so I can't really have another domain do this.  I've looked into Varnish to set cookies but that means that I need to set up a server that will scale.  The scale could be very large ( > 4k requests / sec ) so I dont really trust myself to setup a load-balancer/EC2 configuration with any real confidence.

I am really hoping that someone has already solved this.  If there isn't a service to do this what would the cheapest setup (CPU/resource wise) be?

Answer (score 1):

You can do only with Varnish, you need something like this:

```
set req.http.Cookie = "HAS_VISITED=true;";
```